# How to CONCAT numbers with filled zero values in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, concatenation

I need to generate a ten digits product code (for bar code generation) for a fashion store, which is a combination of:

collectionYear (this or next year), two digits, e.g. 14 or 15

collectionSeason (spring to winter) one digit, e.g. 1 for spring

productId (from 1 to 99.999 with zeros filled), e.g. 12 -> 00012

productVariant (from 1 to 99 with zero filled), e.g. 2 -> 02

The result should be something like this: 1510001202

Using php I would do this like this:

```
$year = str_pad($year, 2 ,'0', STR_PAD_LEFT); // for future safety, e.g. 2102 :-)
$prodId = str_pad($prodId, 5 ,'0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
$prodVar = str_pad($prodVar, 2 ,'0', STR_PAD_LEFT);

$finalCode = $year.$season.$prodId.$prodVar;
```

Is there a mysql syntax equiv for this like

```
SELECT CONCAT(collectionYear,collectionSeason,productIdproductVariant) AS prodCode
```

with the zero fill functions included ??

Thanks for your engagement.

Comment: Simple PHP solution would be to multiply the value by 1 (instead of str_pad()). But better it could be solved in database end.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_rpad

Comment: @MarcB : This is the best and fastest answer, thanks a lot ! Have a nice day !

Comment: in my case LPAD http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_lpad :-)

Comment: final result SELECT CONCAT(LPAD(collectionYear,2,'0'),collectionSeason,LPAD(prodID,5,'0'),LPAD(prodVar,2,'0')) AS prodCode